Can't set paper size or save default printer options for Dymo LabelWriter 450
I have a Dymo LabelWriter 450 with a roll of 99014 shipping labels installed. I'm using Kubuntu 23.10 and the default autodetected printer driver for this printer.
I have a label template set up in gLabels for the 99014 shipping label and have used this in the past successfully. For some time now, though, possibly since upgrading to Kubuntu 23.10, the printer properties dialog in gLabels won't let me select the appropriate label type, it just defaults to the first one in the list, which is 11351:

I can open the Page size dropdown and select the different options, but if I click or press Enter on any one of them, the selected one still stays on 11351.
If I open the printer properties from LibreOffice Write, it looks entirely different and the paper size dropdown defaults to the 30323 label.
Additionally, if I go to the system-wide configuration options for this printer and change the default settings for papier size, resolution, etc., save the settings, close out the dialog and then open it again, all the settings have reverted back to their previous state. So the changed settings are effectively not being saved.
I'm able to print to the printer, though. For example, if I print a 99014 address label PDF from Okular, I can make all the required settings in the print dialog and the label gets printed correctly. So the printer does generally work, it's just that the default settings won't save and I can't select the correct paper size in some printer properties dialogs, namely gLabels and LibreOffice Write (possibly others).
I've removed and re-added the printer, but the issues remain. I'd appreciate any pointers to what might be causing this.

In general it would be right to be harsh about moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.  In this instance, moving forward is not a good recommendation for awhile.  This involves using a printer which I believe would be rendered unusable with the version of Libreoffice on 24.04 until an open bug is fixed.  Moving backward to 22.04 which is a long term release would not have the LO bug

That LO bug is  'All printing is in landscape format'  https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=154975

It is possible to go forward to 24.04, provided something is done to work around the LO problem.  That's discussed in https://askubuntu.com/questions/1513133/how-would-the-version-of-libreoffice-in-24-04-be-rolled-back-to-a-previous-versi

Sorry people, I got the Kubuntu version wrong and corrected it to 23.10. Of course this version is almost EOL too and I will probably make the upgrade to 24.04 soon, although now that I've learned about the LO problem, I might be holding off for a bit.
